# In Java how to add field to json using com.amazonaws jmespath-java?

Tags: java, aws-sdk, json-query

i am trying to query json using com.amazonaws jmespath-java from https://mvnrepository.com/open-source/json-query.

I didn't find documentation of usage of above library in Java.

Querying is possible in javascript,python and i am looking to consume in Java

Can you help me with documentation